# How to get store value using Ngrx

Tags: angular, ngrx

I'm trying to get a value from the store in NGRX

**This is what i am trying to do:**

```
  ngOnInit(){
    this.store.select('appReducer').subscribe(data => {
      console.log('this is the data:' + data);
      this.sdk = data.sdk;
      this.authentication = data.auth;
    });
  }
```

**This is how the data looks like:**

```
export interface AppData {
    sdk: any;
    auth: any;  
}
```

but i can only access the value using  (data[x].var)
how can i access the data using it's key and not it's position 
what i want to do is > data.key.var

how do i achieve this ?

Comment: Hey, welcome to StackOverflow! What's the console.log output? Would help to see how the data looks like.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `map` for this purpose 
e.g.

```
 this.store.select('appReducer')
  .subscribe(data=> {
    this.dataFromStore= data.map(temp => {
      return {
        sdk: temp.sdk,
        auth: temp.auth
      };
    });
  });
```

then you can use `this.dataFromStore` for further processing

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not a real answer to your question, but you should take a look at selectors. 
You can see selectors as queries on top of your store.

Some links that might help:

- [NgRx
  docs](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/store/selectors.md)
- [NgRx example-app](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/projects/example-app/src/app/books/reducers/index.ts#L76)
- [Alex Okrushko's talk - NgRx: Selectors are more powerful than you think](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E7GKnjGCXzU)